# How can you find Quality Factor of an arbitrary RLC Circuit?

Tags: frequency, passive-networks, resonance, input-impedance, damping-factor

[image]

I'm having a trouble with this circuit. Apparently I know how to deal with a simple RLC circuit but this one is tricky

Comment: What do you want to do, determine the impedance of this network? If this is \$Z(s)\$ that you want, I can see using the FACTs a zero brought by the inductor and its series resistance. The denominator will follow the form \$D(s)=1+\frac{s}{Q\omega_0}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2\$. Determine the impedance using the method of your choice and factor your expression so that the denominator is of the form I gave. Then by identification, find \$\omega_0\$ and \$Q\$.

Comment: If you know how to deal with this for a simple RLC, why don't you show that then we can point you where to re-apply when using two resistors. You choose which resistor to remove and do the Q math then someone will step in to show you when both R's are present

Comment: Q is energy stored divided by energy dissipated by cycle, or at least it's of that form, maybe there's a factor of 2 or 2pi to go in. But given the component values, you can work out the energy stored easily for some level of excitation, and then knowing the currents and voltages, work out the power dissipated per cycle in those resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I know how to deal with a simple RLC circuit but this one is tricky*

Convert the parallel resistor into a series resistor by doing this: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.emcourse.com/converting-parallel-rl-circuits-their-easier-work-series-equivalents.html).

Once done, add it to the existing series resistor and you're good to go. However, you need to find the frequency at which the Q is determined. If that happens to be the resonant frequency use this along the way: -

$$Fc = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

My calculations led me to believe that Fc is 112.54 Hz. So, you'll need to know that.

Comment: Thanks! I got the point. This was really helpful

Answer (score 3):

If you want to determine the impedance \$Z_{in}(s)\$ of this network, you can apply the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs described in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) I wrote. To do so, the stimulus you need to apply the network across the network is reduced to 0 A and you "look" across each energy-storing components to express the resistance you "see":

[image]

The zero is determined by nulling the response when the excitation is back. It means determining the impedance condition in this circuit for which \$V_T\$ becomes 0 V. And this is when the inductance and its series resistance form a transformed short circuit leading to: \$\omega_z=\frac{R_1}{L_2}\$.

Once you have determined all these elements, a quick Mathcad sheet lets you test the raw expression versus the one determined using the FACTs. The quality factor \$Q\$ is determined by identifying the factors in the denominator with those of the formalized 2nd-order polynomial:

[image]

If we consider \$R_1\$ fairly small compared to \$R_2\$, we can write \$Q=\frac{R_2\sqrt{C_1L_2}}{L_2+C_1R_1R_2}\$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be arrived at much more easily if you use the series to parallel conversion. Near resonance the series L-R circuit can be converted into parallel L-R configuration as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRm94j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The series resistance is converted into a parallel resistance which increased (approximately) by square of the quality factor of inductor.
$$R_{L} = Q_L^2R_s = (\frac{\omega_oL}{R_s})^2R_s = \frac{L}{CR_s}$$
Thus the total equivalent resistance becomes parallel combination of the resistor \$R_L\$ and that due to capacitor \$R_c\$:
$$R_{eq} = \frac{\frac{L}{CR_s}R_c}{\frac{L}{CR_s}+R_c}$$
$$R_{eq} = \frac{LR_c}{L+CR_cR_s}$$
Thus the overall quality factor is:
$$Q_{eq} = \omega_oR_{eq}C = \frac{\sqrt{LC}R_c}{L+CR_cR_s}$$

Another easy way would be to use:
$$\frac{1}{Q_{eq}} = \frac{1}{Q_{L}} + \frac{1}{Q_{C}}$$
Both of which are pretty easy to compute.